# Jquery Date Validation- due date >= start date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
    }

    function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ];
      var date = new Date(date);
      return date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date.getMonth() + 1)] + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
    }

    var datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));
    $("#startdate").val(datewithformate)

    var datewithformate1 = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));

    $("#enddate").val(datewithformate1)

while(Date.parse(datewithformate1) < Date.parse(datewithformate))
{


    $("#enddate").val(datewithformate1)
}
```

I want my end date to always be >= (greater than equal to) start date. I tried the parse method. While the code is running, it is not giving me the desired output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Enddate can not always be greater then equal to start date. As you are calling random function. Which randomize date everytime.
But You can trace when it can be greater or equal and when not.

```
    function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
    }

    function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ];
      var date = new Date(date);
      return date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date.getMonth() + 1)] + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
    }

    var datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));
    $("#startdate").val(datewithformate)

    var datewithformate1 = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));

    $("#enddate").val(datewithformate1)
    DateRecursion();

// if end date is greater then equal to start date...
function DateRecursion() {
      if(Date.parse(datewithformate1) >= Date.parse(datewithformate))
      {
          alert("end date is greater then equal to start date");
      }
      datewithformate1 = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));
      datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));
      DateRecursion();
}
```

I suppose your html like

```
<label>Start date</label><br><input type="text" id="startdate" />
<label>End date</label><br><input type="text" id="enddate" />
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought of the alert message pop up but I want it to be like if the end date is less than the start date,it should regenerate a random date and should keep on regenerating until the condition is met. You see, everything is automated. The complete code (not posted here) automatically enters random values in respective fields. I want the same for date. Is there a tweak for that?

Comment: oh okay. Let me try.

Comment: now see i edited the code. But it will go infinite. There will always end date  be greater then and equal to start date.

Comment: Thank you for trying but it's not helping. I appreciate the effort though.